# Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt. Even after making changes to bash_profile

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mean-stack, mean.io

I've followed several of the answers from other posts, but am still getting the same error. I am using mean.io framework for my project and am supposed to use the command `grunt` in terminal to run my server.

grunt -version:

```
grunt-cli v0.1.13
```

.bash_profile:

```
ESC="\033" # This is the escape sequence
NO_COLOR="$ESC[0m"
IRED="$ESC[1;31m" # ANSI color code for intense/bold red
IGRN="$ESC[1;32m" # ANSI color code for intense/bold green

# From http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/02/02/bedazzle-your-bash-prompt-with-git-info/
# I had to change 'git-symbolic-ref' to 'git symbolic-ref'
function parse_git_branch {
  ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return
  echo " ["${ref#refs/heads/}"]" # I wanted my branch wrapped in [], use () or <> or whatever
}

# from http://ariejan.net/2010/04/25/ruby-version-and-gemset-in-your-bash-prompt-yes-sir
function rvm_version {
  local gemset=$(echo $GEM_HOME | awk -F'@' '{print $2}')
  [ "$gemset" != "" ] && gemset="@$gemset"
  local version=$(echo $MY_RUBY_HOME | awk -F'-' '{print $2}')
  [ "$version" != "" ] && version="$version"
  local full="$version$gemset"
  [ "$full" != "" ] && echo "${full}:" # the colon at the end is a delimiter, you could use a space instead
}

#PS1="\h:\W \u\$" # For reference, here's the default OS X prompt
#export PS1="\$(rvm_version)\W \$(parse_git_branch)\$ " # Without the colors

# I had to put the \[ and \] down here, as opposed to $IRED, to avoid wrapping funkiness.
export PS1="\[$IRED\]\$(rvm_version)\[$NO_COLOR\]\W\[$IGRN\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$NO_COLOR\] \$ "

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstuorial_rails_4_0/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstuorial_rails_4_0/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstuorial_rails_4_0/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstuorial_rails_4_0/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin

export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.24/bin/:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin:$PATH
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I need the server to test my routes and controllers. Please let me know if more information is required.

Error from running npm install:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-watch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-concurrent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-mocha-test
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-concurrent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-watch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-mocha-test

> mean@0.1.2 postinstall /Users/kelvinyu/fullstack/pleasetakeit
> node node_modules/bower/bin/bower install

bower                       EMALFORMED Failed to read /Users/kelvinyu/fullstack/pleasetakeit/bower.json

Additional error details:
Unexpected token }

npm ERR! mean@0.1.2 postinstall: `node node_modules/bower/bin/bower install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mean@0.1.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mean package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node node_modules/bower/bin/bower install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mean
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.24/bin/node" "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.24/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/kelvinyu/fullstack/pleasetakeit
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kelvinyu/fullstack/pleasetakeit/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Have you run `npm install` in the project directory?

Comment: I get an error which I'll post above.

Comment: The way I understand this message is that grunt is fine, but npm install is malforming at bower. Is this correct?

Comment: So `bower.json` is malformed. That needs to get fixed. "Unable to find local grunt" usually means either `npm install` has not been run or you're executing the command from the wrong folder. It may be that the malformed `bower.json` is preventing the local grunt from installing. Also note that there are two parts to grunt: the cli which is usually installed globally and the local grunt which is installed to the project folder.

Comment: Should I just run `npm update` and then `npm install` to fix bower? 

Also, I did install grunt-cli with `npm install -g grunt-cli' and grunt with `npm install grunt -g`. Will I need to delete and reinstall grunt locally?